# Unable to modify innerHTML for anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, renderer

I'm trying to add some styles by DOM manipulation using angular renderer2.

I could updated styles for all html elements expect for `anchor`.

In the below e.g, I'm trying to replace this text `www.url.com` with this `World` to an anchor link.

Note: Only trying to change the text, not the `href`

```
  styleList = [
    {
      ori: 'www.url.com',
      replace: 'World'
    }
  ];
```

When I inspect `<a href="wWorld">www.url.com</a>`, `replace` text is getting added to the `href`.

So expected output should be `<a href="wwww.url.com">World</a>`

Why this is happening only to `anchor` tag ?

Below is the function, which will update the DOM

```
styleList.forEach(styleItem => {
  for (const childNode of childNodes) {
    renderer.setProperty(childNode, 'innerHTML', childNode.innerHTML.replace(styleItem.ori, styleItem.replace));
  }
});
```

You can check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxidnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link for reference.

Please help.

Comment: its not about css, it's styleList which will tell what text to replace with

Comment: The problem in your code is that you are replacing the text where event a "href" matches your RegExp. Try to change to `'>www.url.com<'` and `'><i>World</i><'` and this will work. Also you can match space characters if there is any to still work with that. Also I don't think that it's a good idea to change an HTML like you are doing. 1) Using a renderer doesn't make any sence in here. 2) If you need to transform the showing value you can create a pipe that will process a value and match a text using map (obect with key-value pairs)

Comment: Why the `href` is being replaced but not the text you can read here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp in note

Comment: How can I do only for `anchor` ?

Comment: @Sergey I Agree, but this is the way. My design is very complex.

Comment: If you mean by "do only for anchor" pipe usage is simply put between tags `{{ anchorText | transformingPipe:map }}`. Read more about pipes you can on angular.io.

Comment: 1) Why have you chosen to use a renderer? 2) The complex design is bad (the very complex is even worse). You will want to make your design as simple as possible, because it makes it easier to maintain and find the errrors

Comment: If is a complex app, it as many history behind it. is der any way to do it in this function `styleList.forEach(styleItem => {`

Comment: Use native JS without renderer. I suggest using .innerText. It looks more appropriate

Comment: .innerText is not working, in case if need to replace `world` with `<i>world</i>` then it displays everything as text

Comment: is der any way to exclude `<a href>` while replacing ?

Comment: your design is the problem here.  You need to rearchitect

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1blll5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've achieved
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdhle9?file=src/app/style.service.ts

The main thing I did is changed your service to use RegExp groups

```
for (const childNode of childNodes) {
   const regex = new RegExp('<(.*)>' + styleItem.ori + '<(.*)>')

   renderer.setProperty(childNode, 'innerHTML', childNode.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<$1>' + styleItem.replace + '<$2>'));
}
```

Here I create two matching groups which will copy the innner of HTML opening and closing tag.

And then I simply return these groups(tags inner) back to `< >` and place the value between them.

Comment: '<$1>' instead I used '<$open>', why it didn't work ?

Comment: @user007 I guess you can find out it here https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html